# Windows Service constantly looking for files

Tags: c#, windows, asynchronous, service, task

Sorry if this is an stupid question, but I'm pretty new to Windows Services and want to make sure I understand the proper way to approach this situation.

I have a Windows Service that is meant to watch for files and if those files exist, it processes them. I was looking through an old developer's code and they used Thread.Sleep() if files didn't exist. I understand that this is bad practice and have seen it first-hand that this locks up the service.

Here's a simplified example of my logic:

```
private Task _processFilesTask;
private CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource;

public Start()
{
   _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
   _processFilesTask = Task.Run(() => DoWorkAsync(_cancellationTokenSource.Token))
}

public async Task DoWorkAsync(CancellationToken token)
{
   while(!token.IsCancellationRequested)
   {
      ProcessFiles();
      //await Task.Delay(10000);
   }
}

public Stop()
{
   _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
   _processFilesTask.Wait();
}

private void ProcessFiles()
{
  FileInfo xmlFile = new DirectoryInfo(Configs.Xml_Input_Path).GetFiles("*.xml").OrderBy(p => p.CreationTime).FirstOrDefault();
  if(xmlFile != null)
    {
      //read xml
      //write contents to db
      //move document specified in xml to another file location
      //delete xml
    }
}
```

My first question: Is any sort of Delay or Pause even needed? If I don't have any pause then this service will constantly look for files on a remote server. Is this something I have to worry about or is it a pretty light-weight process?

Second question: If it would be better to pause instead of constantly hitting this server, is this a better approach or what would you recommend?

```
public  async Task DoWorkAsync(CancellationToken token)
{
   while(!token.IsCancellationRequested)
   {
      ProcessFiles();
      await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10000), token).ContinueWith(_processFilesTask=> { });
   }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You haven't shown how it looks for the files so we can't say if it's lightweight or not. But usually it's better to have a delay, otherwise there may be busy loops which just suck all resources. And yes, Task.Delay is what you want to use

Comment: Oops, I updated my code. In this example, if tries to find .xml files ordered by creation time and checks if they exist. 75% of the day, there will be no files in this directory. Would it be better to use a delay instead of constantly doing the .GetFiles() method?

Comment: You definitely want some kind of pause. Continuously probing a server is a huge waste of CPU and network resources. Have you considered just using a [Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx)? There's also the [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) approach, but I've found that it's less than reliable when monitoring remote folders/files.

Comment: That's sort of what I was thinking. I've looked into Timers and read a little about FileSystemWatcher but people have said the same thing. I thought I read that the disadvantage to a timer is that it kicks off a new thread each time the timer is ready, even if the previous thread is still processing, is this correct? I really only need one thread to be running so maybe the Delay is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

You can use timer to check desired files and folder. Here is outline.

1. Add Timer in your service class (one that inherits ServiceBase class)

   private System.Timers.Timer myTimer;
2. Initialize timer in OnStart method.

   ```
   protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
   {
       // Set the Interval to 1 seconds (1000 milliseconds).
       myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);

       // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer.
       myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);

       myTimer.Enabled = true;

   }
   ```
3. Define elapsed event handler.

   ```
   private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
   {
       //Write your file handling logic here.
       //Service will execute this code after every one second interval
       //as set in OnStart method.
   }
   ```

Comment: What's the benefit of using a timer here?

Comment: Using timed event service will check for files at specified intervals and not all time.

Comment: But what's the benefit over having a delay, like the OP has?